# How to make crystal report in visual studio from MariaDB

Tags: model-view-controller, crystal-reports, mariadb

i'm new in crystal report. I want to make a crystal report in ASP.NET Web Application (MVC) but when i want to add ADO.NET entity data model, i can't find the connection for MariaDB, all the connection is for MySQL. I can't find my database if i choose MySQL connector. Anyone know how to add connector for MariaDB ? Please Help thanks

[data source connection options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIv0r.png)

Answer (score 0):

My experience is not with using Crystal through .Net. However, you could try the MariaDB [connector](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlconnector-for-adonet/).
In the desktop/server version of Crystal Reports 2016, I found the MySQL odbc connector did not work for MariaDB. I used an ODBC connector from DevArt.